# How to run javascript with no viewer input

Tags: javascript, inputbox

I have a javascript effect that was written for viewer input.
How do I randomize the values, thus removing the viewer interaction? I can remove the labels, but the numbers are still visible.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div id="control-box">
        <div>
            <label>Num Raindrops</label>
            <input id="num-rain" type="number" value="250" min="1" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Rain Angle</label>
            <input id="angle" type="number" value="20" min="0" max="90" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Angle Tightness</label>
            <input id="tightness" type="number" value="0" min="0" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Raindrop Length</label>
            <input id="length" type="number" value="20" min="0" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Variable Raindrop Length</label>
            <input id="var_length" type="number" value="0" min="0" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Raindrop Speed</label>
            <input id="speed" type="number" value="7" min="0" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Variable Raindrop Speed</label>
            <input id="var_speed" type="number" value="0" min="0" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <canvas id="rain"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hey Nikki! Could you show us the JavaScript as well for this project, and explain what you're looking for in a bit more detail?

It sounds to me like you'd like to remove the `form` aspect of it entirely, and have the JavaScript randomly generate the values, and execute the code - does this sound correct?

Comment: @Ryan Nice comment. It's refreshing to see someone so polite and ready to help.

Comment: Yes, exactly! I don't want the form, just the cool effect.

Comment: `document.querySelector('#control-box').style.display = 'none';`

Comment: Thanks Will! That worked!!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so you've already solved most of what you're looking to do. This post is without knowing what your JavaScript looks like, so bear with me:

You've set up your ranges already in your DOM elements, so translate that to your JavaScript, you could do something like:

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

var numRaindrops = getRandomArbitrary(1, 1000); //minimum 1 drop, maximum 1000
var rainAngle = getRandomArbitrary(0, 90); //minimum 0 deg, maximum 90deg
var tightness = getRandomArbitrary(min, max);
...
```

And then pass those values to the function that draws the canvas. Doing it this way ensures that the default `value="{{value}}"` that you've set isn't the ONLY value that can be produced by the code!

Now, if you're just looking to hide the form, and use the DOM you've created to grab values still (again, to my understanding this would make the values `static` rather than being `dynamic`, you could just use `css` and `display:none` the inputs, so they don't show up on the screen.